# Como criar pastas na área de trabalho em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu estava querendo fazer um programa em python que criasse uma pasta na área de trabalho, assim o fiz:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('mkdir Pasta_Teste', shell= True)
```

Mas o código criava uma pasta dentro da pasta do projeto, logo, tentei usar um comando do prompt que abria a área de trabalho, para depois criar a pasta, tentei isto:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('cd Desktop', shell= True)
subprocess.call('mkdir Pastinha', shell= True)
```

E recebi este erro:

```
O sistema n�o pode encontrar o caminho especificado.
```

E logo após isso ele criou a pasta, mas na pasta do projeto
Como posso fazer ele criar uma pasta na Área de trabalho?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O seu código usando `subprocess.call('cd Desktop', shell= True)` não funciona pois o `subprocess.call()` funciona como um comando único apenas, então quando voce roda ele com o `cd`, *pode ser* que ele esteja de fato indo para o diretório que você pediu, mas em seguida você roda um novo `subprocess.call()` para executar o `mkdir`, então neste momento o `mkdir` funciona com um novo comando, ou seja, ele não está na pasta que você espera que ele esteja.

Você pode tentar resolver com `os.chdir()`:

```
os.chdir("/desktop") # lembre-se de usar o caminho absoluto para a pasta
subprocess.call('mkdir Pasta_Teste2', shell= True)
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sim 0 isso vai funcionar para um script simples, mas como detalhei na minha resposta, confiar em mudança de diretório para o processo inteiro não é a solução ideal.

Answer (score 7):

## Resumo

Trabalhar com diretórios no shell é diferente de trabalhar com diretórios de dentro de um programa - transplantar os comandos não vai funcionar.

Mesmo assim, há coisas específicas no uso de diretórios com programas que o
Python só simplificou depois da versão 3.5 - no texto completo eu explico melhor.
Mas, para o sue problema específico, você pode fazer:

```
from pathlib import Path

desktop = Path.home() / "Desktop"
pastinha = desktop.mkdir("Pastinha")
```

e, daí pra frente, para qualquer operaçao com arquivos nessa pasta - por exemplo,
criar um arquivo "dados.db" lá dentro:

```
arq = open(pastinha / "dados.db", "wt")
```

Note que não foi usado "chdir" ou equivalente - explico abaixo.

## Criar um diretório em Python

Primeiro: chamar `supprocess.call("mkdir pastinha")` para criar uma pasta é o mesmo que telefonar para um chaveiro para abrir a porta da sua casa, quando você está com a chave na mão. Em vez de colocar a chave na porta e girar, você espera até o chaveiro vir, pegar as ferramentas dele, abrir a porta, e paga a taxa pra ele.

Isso por que desta forma o mkdir é invocado como um processo externo do sistema operacional - o sistema tem que criar um novo processo na tabela de processos, reservar os recursos para o mesmo, *ler* do HD o arquivo com o binário do mkdir, e encerrar o processo em seguida. Tudo isso em geral acontece muito rápido, mas usa umas mil a 10 mil vezes mais recursos computacionais do que simplesmente fazer a chamada ao sistema operacional para criar um diretório.

Essa pode ser feita diretamente do Python usando-se o módulo `os`: `os.mkdir("Pastinha")`.

A partir do Python 3.5 no entanto, há uma nova API para tudo que é relacionado ao sistema de arquivos, que é a pathlib - ela tem um objeto unificado para representar nomes de arquivos ou diretórios, que já tem métodos para abrir ou ler um arquivo diretamente, ou criar um novo diretório embaixo daquele. Com a pathlib, o código completo seria:

```
from pathlib import Path
desktop = Path.home() / "Desktop"
desktop.mkdir("Pastinha")
```

(o uso de `getpass.getuser` para pegar o nome do usuário foi sugerido  pelodo RafaelTuber em outra resposta, eu não iria lembrar de fazer isso. Mas o Anderson lembrou (nos comentários) que existe o `Path.home()` que faz isso de forma mais direta, dispensando saber o nome do usuário)

## Mudando de diretório

**Você *não* muda de diretório!** :-)

Aqui é que está o que faz o seu código não funcionar. A questão de "estar em um diretório" é algo relativo - o "diretório de trabalho" é uma variável de cada processo (programa) que está rodando. Antes de chamar o programa em Python, se estamos num terminal (tipo o `cmd`), mudamos até o diretório desejado com `cd pasta/pasta<enter>`. Quando o programa é chamado, o diretório de trabalho dele é esse do qual ele foi chamado "pasta/pasta" - se você usar qualquer caminho de arquivo relativo (isso é, sem começar com uma "/" ou "\" que volta à raiz do file-system, é nesse diretório que as ações acontecem). E isso acontece por que tem uma variável interna do sistema operacional, associada ao seu programa, que fala que o "diretório de trabalho corrente" (CWD) é essa "pasta/pasta".

Se o seu próprio programa faz uma chamada ao sistema operacional dizendo "estou mudando a pasta de trabalho do programa atual", ela é atualizada. Se o seu programa chamar `os.chdir("../outra_pasta")`,  o sistema operacional entende que o "diretório de trabalho corrente" (CWD) agora é "pasta/outra_pasta". Só que quando o seu programa acaba, e você volta para o cmd, qual é o CWD do cmd? Justamente o "pasta/pasta" - ele não se moveu só por que o processo filho, o seu programa em Python, mudou o próprio diretório.

Quando você usa um subprocesso pra chamar o "chdir" a mesma coisa acontece. O "chdir" é um comando embutido no shell. No caso do Windows o próprio "cmd". O sistema operacional então cria um novo processo, executa um novo CMD internamente, como descrevi acima, esse cmd chama o sistema operacional pra mudar *o próprio* diretório de trabalho para outro - -e se encerra. A execução do seu programa de Python continua no diretório de trabalho em que estava antes.

**No entanto** a história não acaba aí - mesmo chamando `os.chdir(...)`, e alterando corretamente o diretório de trabalho do seu programa, essa prática não é recomendada em programas modernos. Isso por que, como o diretório de trabalho é um estado de todo o programa, qualquer função que altere o mesmo vai alterar o diretório tambemnas funções que a chamaram, e qualquer outro lugar do programa - ou seja,não é uma mudança "estanque". Se o programa for multi-thread então, a situação é pior ainda.  Em outras palavras: num programa mais complexo que use mudança de diretório, não dá uma parte do programa saber qual é o diretório atual  - outra função pode ter mudado o diretório.

A boa prática então é que toda e qualquer ação no sistema de arquivos use o caminho absoluto - começando desde o diretorio "/", ou, no caso do Windows, desde o nome do drive: "C:/". Antes da pathlib isso implicava que programas que iriam garantidamente funcionar tinham que ficar usando `os.path.join` o tempo todo - com a Pathlib isso fica bem mais simples.

## Como proceder para realizar ações em um diretório específico

Em Python moderno então, em vez de tentar mudar o diretório, o mais correto
e mais simples é guardar o diretório onde você quer fazer as operações numa variavel, e, para qualquer operação - seja criar um arquivo, outro diretório, etc... usar o operador `/` (o mesmo usado para divisão de números - ele é ressignificado para objetos da Pathlib) para criar novos objetos `Path`:

```
desktop = pathlib.Path("/users/xxxx/Desktop")
minha_pasta = desktop.mkdir("Minha Pasta")
# Criar novo arquivo para scrita dentro dessa nova pasta:

with (minha_pasta / "meu_arquivo.txt").open("wt") as arq:
   # dentro deste bloco, "arq" é o arquivo
   # DEsktop/Minha Pasta/meu_arquivo.txt" aberto para escrita
   ....
```

Comment: Sobre chegar até a Desktop do usuário, não poderia ser `Path.home() / 'Desktop'`, que usa como base `os.path.expanduser()`?

Comment: Ah - pode também - melhor do que usar do `getpass`,  que nesse caso nem precisa ser importado

Answer (score 1):

Pega do sistema o nome do usuário com getpass.

```
import subprocess
import getpass
usuario = getpass.getuser()
subprocess.call('mkdir C:\\Users\\' + usuario + '\\Desktop\\Pasta_Teste', shell= True)
```

editado removido "" por '' teste e funcionou

Comment: A ideia de pegar o nome do usuário e usar um caminho absoluto é legal. Mas a falha acontece mesmo pq. ele tenta mudar de diretório em um sub-processo.

Comment: (eu inclui a sua sugestão na minha resposta - assim ficam todas as boas práticas e um exemplo completo num lugar só)

Comment: Blz obrigado e que sou novo aqui mais a sobre a dica que eu dei eu mesmo testei aqui usando dentro do sub-processo e funcionou espero que ele tenha conseguido

Answer (score 1):

Para criarmos uma pasta dentro do **Desktop** devemos utilizar a seguinte lógica:

1. Especificar o nome da pasta que desejamos criar no Desktop;
2. Acessar o Desktop;
3. Verificar se a pasta desejada já existe dentro do Desktop;
4. Caso a pasta desejada não exista dentro do Desktop, criar a referida pasta;
5. Se posicionar dentro da referida pasta.

Com esta lógica podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
from os import mkdir, chdir, getcwd, path
import os.path

pas = input('Digite o nome da pasta: ')

cam = path.join(path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop')
chdir(cam)

if os.path.isdir(pas):
    print(f'A pasta "{pas}" já existe em Desktop!')

else:
    mkdir(pas)
    cam2 = cam + '\\' + pas
    chdir(cam2)
    print(getcwd())
```

Observe que quando executamos o código, devemos informar o nome da **pasta** que desejamos criar e pressionar `Enter`.

A partir deste momento o código entrará no Desktop do respectivo usuário, verificará se a pasta deseja já existe em suas dependências e, caso negativo, criará a referida pasta e se posicionará dentro dela. Caso positivo, exibe uma mensagem dizendo que a referida pasta já existe.

Answer (score -1):

Passe o caminho completo para a área de trabalho... Neste caso ele está procurando a pasta: Desktop dentro da pasta do seu projeto, e como não encontra ele apresenta este erro.